# Web button that hovers and displays drop-shadow on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget

I would like to know how to have a button (clicking on it simply links to another page) with some features.

1) The button is an image-button with no text

2) When the user mouses over the button, I would like it to smoothly animate upwards, so it floats just a little (perhaps 20px?) above where it used to be

3) When the button hovers, it should cast a small shadow on its baseline. I mean a dropshadow, not a shadowed border - a shadow as if the noonday sun were above and casting a downwards ellipse-like shadow on the ground.

Essentially I am looking to have a button with a very aesthetic feel to it. A javascript or jquery solution would be perfect.

Thanks in advance!

(I should mention that I have googled for this a LOT, however the best term to describe the button's functionality is "hovering" and I get all results related to mouse-"hovering" implementation instead of the actual visible button "hovering")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is basic example of transition and box sadhow using css. you can animate the button upwards using margin and transition.

html

```
<button></button>
```

css

```
button {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    color black;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    border: none;
    background-image: url('your image');
}
button:hover {
    margin-top: 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px  grey;
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/caknopal/mmr4F/

for js, you can use jquery animate to animating the button.

css

```
button.hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px  grey;
}
```

js

```
$('button').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).animate({'margin-top':0}, 200);
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});
$('button').on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).animate({'margin-top':20}, 200);
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/caknopal/mmr4F/3/

Comment: This is a great answer and almost exactly what I was looking for. I may have not been too clear about the shadow - I'm looking for a small ellipse-like shadow "on the ground" as if the noonday sun were above the hovering box, casting a shadow under it; not like the border-shadow you've created. I'll give you the check if you can help me out with that!

Comment: you just need to improve this source, don't wait for absolute answer. http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: fair enough! Thanks for the help :)